# manipulate CSS animations with javascript

Tags: javascript

This is a simple question, but I'm pretty new to programming and I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

I have a div that moves on a button press

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var box = document.getElementById('box');

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkbox.checked = true;
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
 }

@keyframes moveRight {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(120%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
 }

#checkbox:checked ~ #box {
  animation-name: moveRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

This is a simple animation, so doing it this way isn't really an issue for this case. The issue is when I want to add another animation to it via a checkbox, it sees that both checkboxes are "checked" and it runs both animations. With javascript and without a checkbox, how can I do the following:

-add a css animation
-remove it when I want to use another animation

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain more about your expected behavior? It's not clear to me. Maybe post another example of it *not* working the way you want, or what you have tried to do so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, for example, by adding/removing a css class of box element.
(If I understood your question correctly)

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box1.className = "";
    box1.className += " moving-box-right";
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box1.className = "";
    box1.className += " moving-box-left";
});


#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
 }

@keyframes moveRight {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(120%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
 }
 @keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
 }

.moving-box-right {
  animation-name: moveRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.moving-box-left {
  animation-name: moveLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="button1">Move box right</button>
     <button id="button2">Move box left</button>
    <div id="box1"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kdnzqx52/2/

Comment: Yepp, you definitely understood me correctly! That makes sense now to put the animation inside of a class and just add on that class. Would it be better to use .classlist.add("class") or classlist.remove("class") so I avoid accidentally forgetting the "+"?